# Hi , i wanted to copy a text from HTML </span> to my textbox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

taking  text from HTML and putting into span in VB.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your span server accesible by assigning it id and setting attribute runat="server". This **[article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** descibes well, how to do it.

*Html*

```
<span id="MySpan" runat="server" />
```

*Code behind*

```
textbox1.Text = MySpan.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#<%=textboxID.ClientID%>").val($("#SpanID").text());
});
```

Comment: Question is not tagged for javascript or jquery.